# Eclipse Bluemix plugin 407 auth. error

Tags: eclipse, proxy, ibm-cloud, http-status-code-407, ibm-cloud-tools

I followed the steps of this tutorial:
http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/ega_docs/dialog_ega.shtml#ega_getstart_setup
until the step 3h (Account validation), which leads to following error:
“Client error – 407 Proxy Authorization required”.
(I am behind a company proxy)

I use Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 and   IBM Bluemix Tools 1.0.10.v20160406_1758.

What i have already done:
-Of course I have Bluemix account that works perfectly fine.

-I have filled in the HTTP and HTTPS info within the Eclipse proxy settings (General->network settings) and cleared the SOCK-field. I can therefore install new software and use the eclipse marketplace for instance.

-Set the proxy at the http_proxy/https_proxy at the Windows system variables, therefore I can use the Bluemix command line tool and login to Bluemix.

-Experimenting with adding various lines at the eclipse.ini as in the following:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provi    der.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=YYY.com
-Dhttp.proxyUser=uid123
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXX
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=YYY.com
-Dhttps.proxyUser=uid123
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=XXX
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=3000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=3000
```

The command "nslookup api.ng.bluemix.net" returns:

```
Server:  AAA.de    Address:  aa.bbb.cd.ef  

Not authorized answer:
Name:    ng.bluemix.net      Address:  75.126.70.44       Aliases:                       api.ng.bluemix.net
```

Any suggestions how to successfully use the Eclipse Bluemix Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like you have authentication error on accessing the proxy itself. The Bluemix Tools does not use the command line interface (CLI) to communicate with the Bluemix server. Therefore, proxy settings are not setup in Eclipse even if you have it working using the CLI.

In Eclipse, all the proxy settings can be done from the Preference page. There is no need to change eclipse.ini so you can restore the eclipse.ini file to the original before changing the preference setting. You can find the corresponding preference page in ***Window>Preferences>General>Network*** Connection. Then, change the *"Active Provider"* to *"Manual"* and edit the HTTP and HTTPS port proxy settings as needed.

In the *Edit Proxy Entry* dialog, you can input the proxy authentication information by selecting *Requires Authentication* checkbox and input the user/password.